# org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.NamedStaxOMBuilder comiplation error while upgrading Axis2 1.6.2 to Axis2 1.8(latest)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am upgrading our webservices project from Axis2 1.6.2 to Axis2 1.8 (latest version) version. While running the wsdl2java tool i am getting generated files but in generated file `responseData.xml` (generated file) "`org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.NamedStaxOMBuilder`" for this line i am getting compiler error. This class is deprecated in new version. How to get rid of this ?

```
import org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.NamedStaxOMBuilder;
import org.apache.axis2.databinding.util.StreamWrapper;

NamedStaxOMBuilder builder = new NamedStaxOMBuilder(new StreamWrapper(reader), reader.getName());
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Not sure why the generated clients will reference to this "unexisted" class in 1.8. Have you got any clue to solve this issue ?